# Setting 1-1 Relation to existing object inserts new object instead using JDO?

Tags: java, neo4j, jdo, datanucleus

A new Object is created whenever I try to set it to an object property. Let someone reproduce this. Is it the default behavior?

```
public class ProductClass implements Serializable {
...
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
long id;
@Persistent
private String name = null;
...
}


public class Product implements Serializable {
...
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
long id;
@Persistent
private String name = null;
@Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
private ProductClass productClass = null;
...
}
```

This is how I retrieve `ProductClass` from Database by implementing my `ProductClassNeo4jService`;

```
@Override
public ProductClass findById(Long id) {
    if (id == null) {
        return null;
    }
    PersistenceManager pm
            = JDOUtil.PERSISTENCE_MANAGER_FACTORY.getPersistenceManager();
    ProductClass prod = null;

    try {
        prod = (ProductClass) pm.getObjectById(ProductClass.class, id);
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }
    return prod;
}

...
ProductClass prodClass = productClassNeo4jService.findById(id);
```

Persisting the Product like this;

```
...
Product prod = new Product();
prod.setName('productName');
prod.setProductClass(prodClass);

PersistenceManager pm = JDOUtil.PERSISTENCE_MANAGER_FACTORY.getPersistenceManager();
Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
try {
tx.begin();
pm.makePersistent(prod);
Object id = pm.getObjectId(prod);
tx.commit();
} finally {
    if (tx.isActive()) {
        tx.rollback();
    }
    pm.close();
}
...
```

Instead of setting the ProductClass to the Product, new ProductClass is produced. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is "non-String object"? You have a 1-1 RELATION! Where is `prodClass` created? What object lifecycle state is it in at the point of calling `makePersistent`? All of that is defined in the JDO spec and any decent JDO documentation

Comment: @DN1 Thanks, I have added how I do retrieve `prodClass`. The productClass(es) have already been created. To create a new Product, the Product must belong to one productClass. That is, 1-1 RELATION as you said. Right?

Comment: so it was retrieved outside the transaction, hence is TRANSIENT ? or DETACHED?

Comment: Yes. It was retrieved outside that transaction. You could see I do not use transaction to read data but only when writing to the Database. I think, looking at the model annotation, it is DETACHED. `@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, cacheable = "false", detachable = "true")
public class ProductClass implements Serializable {`

Comment: so look at the log because it tells you all of that, and what is happening ...

Comment: New object is always created; `2017-12-31 16:01:11.837 [qtp1955990522-105] Persist - Object "com.hope.tub.neo4j.jdo.model.Product@12fff467" persisted to Neo4j has had identity set to "150"
2017-12-31 16:01:11.922 [qtp1955990522-105] Persist - Object "com.hope.tub.neo4j.jdo.model.ProductClass@68a8c7a0" being inserted into Neo4j with all reachable objects
2017-12-31 16:01:11.922 [qtp1955990522-105] Native - Persisting StateManager[pc=com.hope.tub.neo4j.jdo.model.ProductClass@68a8c7a0, lifecycle=P_NEW] as Node[151]` I do not know why. lifecycle=P_NEW

Comment: Because it is not detached! Because you did not tell the persistence manger to detach it

Comment: How do I tell the persistence manger to detach it if I am retrieving it outside that particular transaction?

Comment: You read the JDO spec, or any JDO docs, as mentioned before. http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_1/jdo/persistence.html#pm_detach

Comment: I set my `persistence.xml`  property to `datanucleus.DetachAllOnCommit = true`. I will check why it was not detaching. Could it be because it was not on Transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to JDO 2.0 for feature called **attach/detach** that allows to detach objects for use elsewhere, and then attach them when you want to persist any changed data within the object. The `ProductClass` I obtained was useless without detaching it. Thanks to @DN1. I have modified my code to detach the ProductClass, by adding a line.

It looks like this;

```
@Override
public ProductClass findById(Long id) {
    if (id == null) {
        return null;
    }
    PersistenceManager pm
            = JDOUtil.PERSISTENCE_MANAGER_FACTORY.getPersistenceManager();
   Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();

    ProductClass prod = null;

    try {
        tx.begin();

        prod = (ProductClass) pm.getObjectById(ProductClass.class, id);
       // Detach our productClass object for use elsewhere
       prod =  pm.detachCopy(prod);

       tx.commit();
    } finally {
        if (tx.isActive()) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        pm.close();
    }
    return prod;
}
```

For convenience add `javax.jdo.option.DetachAllOnCommit = true` to your PMF option.

The actual problem is that I was doing all these outside **Transaction**.
Adding `javax.jdo.option.DetachAllOnCommit` to your `persistence.xml` works only when on `Transaction`.

Comment: but if you are using a transaction you don't need `detachCopy`. And if you are doing it without a transaction you could just set `datanucleus.detachOnClose` so all read-in objects are detached when you close the PM.

Comment: @DN1 Yes. I have observed that. It took me time, and your assistance to find out why it was not detaching. Thanks.

Comment: Will there be any conflict in setting both `datanucleus.DetachAllOnCommit= true` and `datanucleus.detachOnClose = true` in my `persistence.xml` since I prefer to read Data without a transaction?